# NFS - Mount all child dataset and shares in a master server [Freenas]

Tags: nfs, nas, zfs, mount-point

I'm setting up this configuration:

```
Server A -> /mnt/repository/backups/shareA
Server B -> /mnt/repository/backups/shareB
Server C -> /mnt/repository/backups/shareC
Server D -> /mnt/repository/backups/shareD
...
```

And i need that a master/management server can access to all data and files.
So I need to have:

```
Server Mngmt -> /mnt/repository/
```

However FreeNAS is creating all dataset/volumes mounting them and hiding the contents. So you cannot access to child contents by using a parent mount.
This is the standard behaviour:
https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/jails-mounted-folders-sub-datasets-dont-work.14567/

In my opinion this is fine from a security point of view.
But if I really need to access all dataset under a specific dataset, then how can I?

Do I really have to create all those mounting point manually?

Is there a way to script an automatic access to all shares without everytime update fstab manually?

Answer (score 2):

Ok i found a way to make this work thanks to autofs.
I post the answer maybe can be helpfull with people with my same problem.

Here is a good explanation of the tool i used:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs

Thanks to this I have any NFS share automatically mounted on the master server by using wildcard entries in the config file.
- i don't have to rewrite /fstab every new backup share
- i can work on all mounting point exactly as I'm on my filesystem

It's quite easy to use (learning curve: 1hour).

Max

Comment: If you want to go a bit further, you may appreciate to know that you can store your autofs maps and mounts in a LDAP. So it's distributed across your all client.
A very simple way to setup this is FreeIPA (but easier for RHEL distribs)